How to Stop Rust Truncating Debug Output
I'm working on a project that requires me to talk to an LDAP server so I'm using the ldap3 crate. To test the connection and see the response output I've added a small connection testing tool.
The problem isn't that it's erroring (I mean it is a problem but that's not the issue I'm asking about in this instance) It's that rust is appearing to truncate the Debug output.
Instead of getting a full output of the error all I'm getting is this:
Bind(OpSend { source: SendError { .. } })

I want to see the content of SendError but I can't because it's being truncated.
How do I tell Rust to print out the full output without truncating anything?

There's nothing more to see, since SendError's type parameter T is not required to implement Debug.

But the SendError contains this: <(RequestId, LdapOp, Tag, Option<Vec<RawControl>>, Sender<(Tag, Vec<Control>)>)>, shouldn't it display all that information?

This only means that T is (RequestId, LdapOp, Tag, Option<Vec<RawControl>>, Sender<(Tag, Vec<Control>)>) in this case. This does not change how the implementation of impl<T> Debug for SendError<T> looks. I.e. the implementation of Debug for SendError<T> is independent of T and will never show T.

SendError occurs because the receiver was closed. The "truncated" part of the output is the message that couldn't be sent and is therefore unrelated to the error condition. If you still need to see it, you will have to print it yourself explicitly.

As a workaround you could unpack T manually and debug it.

@Jmb, I see so it's truncated because it would just be printing out information that I would/should already know, so the debug implementation is what actually truncates the output, not Rust. I see I miss-understood, that's helpful to know in this specific context.
